# Where to download the Forvo database?

Tags: data-request, language, audio

Forvo.com is a website where native speakers submit pronunciation of words.

The audio data is under the BY-NC-SA license.

I can't find any obvious place to download the whole data.

There is an [API](http://api.forvo.com/), but it only allows 500 requests/day, which means I would need 15 years to download the 2,740,170 pronunciations.

Where to download the whole data?

This is for use in an open source [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki) from which I don't get any money, so my budget is zero.

Comment: This page indicates it is a paid service. http://api.forvo.com/plans-and-pricing/

Comment: I would chip in to buy a month subscription of the Corporate level API, providing that the data can legally be released as a bulk download (with attribution).

Comment: @philshem: This is for use in my open source app AnkiDroid, so budget is zero. It is not clear whether the license for Corporate Plan is Creative Commons-based or not, and in particular whether it allows redistribution or not.

Comment: api.forvo.com says Commercial and Corporate levels allow commercial use.

Comment: Yes but it is not clear whether it allows redistribution or not. Probably not actually.

Comment: I just noticed they actually advertise the non-profit tier (2$ per month) for use with Anki - *For academic and individual use with Anki, GoldenDict etc*

Answer (score 2):

I guess because it's part of Anki, it's somewhat related, but I just stumbled on this

**[A half-automatic Forvo Downloader](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1407979740)**

> 1. You select the field you want the audio to go into and press an editor button or keyboard shortcut.
> 2. The addon will open the relevant forvo.com page in your web browser.
> 3. You decide on one or more pronunciations and download them the regular way in your web browser.
> 4. The addon will automatically pick up the files from your web browser's downloads directory and insert them into the field.

Source code: https://github.com/yunidatsu/anki-forvodl